# Is it possible to have a linear order that is not "on a line"?

Tags: relations, order-theory

I am looking at some problems on linear order. It seems in all the problems, I am dealing with things that are 1D

Whether it is $\mathbb{R}$ itself, or $\left\{\dfrac{1}{n}|n \in \mathbb{Z}_+\right\}\;$ or $\;\mathbb{Q}$.

When I think of orders on the plane,  the first thing that comes to my mind is the lexicographic/dictionary order, which is not a linear order.

So my question is whether there are linear orders on sets that are higher dimensional, or not on a line.

Comment: What do you mean by "dimension", or "line"?

Comment: For example $\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{N}$ are all linear order with $\leq$. Can we have say product of those sets that are also linear order? At the moment the only order I am aware of in higher dimension is the dictionary order which is not a linear order

Comment: Pick your favourite linear order on $\mathbb{R}$ and your favourite bijection $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ and define an order on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by setting $x<y$ iff $f(x)<f(y)$

Comment: Unless we're talking about ordered groups or other algebraic structure the underlying structure of the set is irrelevant, $\mathbb{R}^n$ has the same cardinality for every positive integer so you can use a bijection to transport the order from $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Moreover the lexicographical order on the cartesian product of linearly ordered sets is again a linear order

Comment: "[T]he first thing that comes to my mind is the lexicographic/dictionary order, which is not a linear order". The lexicographic order *is* a [linear order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order). What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: Maybe what OP means to ask is "can any linear order be embedded in $(\mathbb R,\geq)$?".

Comment: That Dennis Rodman guy seems like a real douche

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look at your question's comments to start.

To go in a slightly different direction, you might want to consider the [well-ordering theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_theorem) which states that every set can be well-ordered. This immediately implies that $\mathbb{R}$ can be well-ordered. And, surprisingly (or not so), no well-order on $\mathbb{R}$ has been explicitly given. So, if a well-order (which is linear) on $\mathbb{R}$ exists, it is probably extremely complicated.

You're comment about 'not on a line' and dimensionality does not make a lot of sense. In its most abstract form, a [linear order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) has nothing to do with a line. However, it is often helpful to think about it as such, since it is easy to grasp.

One such example of a set without a 'line' is to consider 
$$\{a,b,c\}$$
and its power set under inclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Note that a linear order might be "too big" to fit in the reals.
For instance, the Hartogs ordinal of the reals is a linear order (indeed, a well-order) but it cannot be embedded in the reals, so in that sense it doesn't "fit on the line".